# (JAVA) contains method with tokenizer string

Tags: java, global-variables, contains, tokenize

So I am using a class to keep a global array for me like this.

```
class keys{
  public static final String[] keys = new String[]{
      "LDA", "MUL"
    };
}
```

There is my class and I am accessing it like this:

```
System.out.println(keys.keys[0]);
```

This prints out LDA.
Now I am reading from a file with a tokenizer and I want to check if the current token I am on ( tokenizer.nextToken() ) is inside the string keys.

I am currently trying stuff like

```
if (keys.keys.contains(tokenizer.nextToken())
```

and its not working, if anyone has any suggestions please let me know!

Comment: Switch to collections. In this case, a `LinkedHashSet`, for instance.

Comment: Whats does the file contain? Seems to be case sensitivity or untrimmed character related problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Stream like

```
if(Arrays.stream(keys.keys).anyMatch(tokenizer.nextToken()::equals))
```